# can I find out "set in stone" exact dates for IPOs?

Tags: stocks, websites, ipo

Do companies have to announce an IPO date they have to stick to? If so, what are good resources to find such IPO dates?

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend:

[Yahoo IPOs](http://biz.yahoo.com/ipo/)

[Renaissance Capital](http://www.renaissancecapital.com/IPOHome/Calendars/OnDeck.aspx)

[Hoovers](http://www.hoovers.com/ipo-central/ipo-calendar/100004161-1.html)

[Market Watch](http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/ipo/ipocenter.asp?v=17)

[IPO Scoop](http://www.iposcoop.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=793&Itemid=99)

[IPO Boutique](http://ipoboutique.com/ipo-calendar.html)

They don't have to stick to the date, by the way. They are times that market forces prompt an underwriter to delay the IPO. You only know for sure the night before, when it "prices."

Anyone with other or better links is welcome to add here if they wish.